# relation between metric and topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have two questions regarding the relationship between metrics and the topology that they generate :

First , if the metric changes then, is it necessary that the topology would also change ?

Second, if two metric generate the same topology, then are they necessarily the same ?

Comment: Answer to both questions is no.

Comment: What is the difference between these questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions are equivalent, so they have the same answer; *no*. For example, if $\langle X,d\rangle$ is any metric spaces, define a new function $\rho:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ by

$$\rho(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\;;$$

then $\rho$ is a metric on $X$ that generates the same topology as $d$ but is pretty clearly not identical to $d$.

Comment: I liked your example, answers both the questions.Could you tell me under what condition would the metrics that generate the same topology be the same?

Comment: @johny: If there are constants $\alpha,\beta>0$ such that $$\alpha d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le\beta d_1(x,y)$$ for all $x,y\in X$, then $d_1$ and $d_2$ generate the same topology on $X$. However, this is only a sufficient condition; $d_1$ and $d_2$ can generate the same topology even if no such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exist. I gave such an example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/511949/12042). I don’t know of any nice condition that is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Alright, got it.

Comment: @johny, I think about the best you can do for necessary and sufficient is this simple but not necessarily easy condition: Two metrics are equivalent (generate the same topology) iff every open *ball* wrt each is an open *set* wrt the other.

Answer (score 4):

As I am the master of the trivial counterexample, I shall present a trivial counterexample!

Let $X = \{0,1\}$. Let $d_1(0,0)=d_2(0,0)=d_1(1,1)=d_2(1,1)=0$ (as required). Let $d_1(0,1)=d_1(1,0)=1$ and $d_2(0,1)=d_2(1,0)=2$. Then both $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics and induce the same topology on $X$.

Answer (score 0):

For example in a nonempty set $X$, the metrices $d_1$ and $d_2$ defined by $d_2(x,y)=\min\lbrace1,d_1(x,y)\rbrace$ generate the same topology on $X$.